# How to crop XYZ file in Qgis

Tags: qgis

I have a large xyz file. it takes me long time to load it to Qgis. I wanted to know that how I can crop the file to my area of interest.

I tried to save the file using extent option but still have problem and Qgis crashes during the saving process.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is in a text file, it would help to first convert your data into shapefile format and create a spatial index. This can be done by opening the General tab in the properties window and clicking the button `Create Spatial Index`.

If you still want to restrict the area of the data to load, you could use the Query Builder to exclude part of your data based on the X and Y coordinates. Something like the following will do the job:

```
"X"< 100  AND "Y" > 50
```